# Why is $\mathbb{R}/(-1,1)$ not Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

My guess would be that $S:=\mathbb{R}/(-1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $S':=(\leftarrow,-1]\cup\{0\}\cup[1,\rightarrow)$ and to somehow show that $S'$ contains points which are non-separable by neighborhoods. Another guess is that I should either consider the points 0 and 1 or 1 and -1. I'm not really sure if this hunch is in any way correct or what I should do next (if it is).

Comment: Hi Tyron, if you mean by $\{0\}$ the point that identifies the interval $(-1,1)$, then intuitively in the quotient topology, this point is infinitely close to both $-1$ and $1$, which means that you cannot separate $-1$ and $1$ by open subsets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem with topology is that I understand such intuitive notions well, but can have a hard time with proving such statements. I was wondering if you could help me understand this notion in a concrete way.

Comment: Well, it definitely requires some time to be familiar with all the formalized language we use in general topology. In this example, the most important thing to write down a rigorous proof is to describe the topology of the quotient space. By the definition of quotient topology, the precise statement corresponding to the idea that 0 is infinitely close to 1 is the following: any open set containing 1 will contain some number close to 1, i.e. in the interval $(-1,1)$, which means in the quotient space, any open set containing 1 will contain 0. Same for -1 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that a Topological space $X$ is **Hausdorff** if for any $x,y\in X$ there exist open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

Considering $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, any open neighborhood of $1$ contains a point in $(-1,1)$.  Thus, with the quotient topology $\mathbb{R}/(-1,1)$, any open neighborhood of $[1]$ (the equivalence class containing $1$, i.e. $[1]=\{1\}$) contains $[0]$ (the equivalence class containing $0$, i.e. $[0]=(-1,1)$).  That is, $[0]$ and $[1]$ cannot be separated by open sets, and thus $\mathbb{R}/(-1,1)$ is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in another way. Consider $$\pi :\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R/(-1;1)$$ you can prove that the space $\Bbb R/(-1;1)$ isn't $T1$. Indeed consider the equivalence class of the $[0]$ and $\pi ^{-1} ([0])=(-1;1)$ which is open but not closed in $\Bbb R$